# Typing Mongoose validation functions

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am helping with a typescript app using MongoDB to persist data. One of the things that we are trying to do is to get rid of `any` usage.

The below code used to define a part of the mongoose schema:

```
priceMax: {
  max: 10000000,
  min: 0,
  required: function (this: FeePricing & Document) {
    return this.priceMin === undefined;
  },
  type: Number,
  validate: [
    {
      message: 'Max price cannot be lower than min price',
      validator: function (v: number) {
        if ((this as any).priceMax === null || (this as any).priceMax === undefined) return true;
        return (this as any).priceMin ? v >= (this as any).priceMin : v >= 0;
      },
    },
    {
      message: 'Max price cannot be higher than 50000 for this feeType',
      validator: function (v: number) {
        return !(!feeTypesWithoutMaxLimit.includes((this as any).feeType) && v > 50000);
      },
    },
  ],
},
priceMin: {
  max: 10000000,
  min: 0,
  required: function () {
    return (this as any).priceMax === undefined;
  },
  type: Number,
  validate: {
    message: 'priceMin cannot be higher than priceMax',
    validator: function (v: number) {
      return (this as any).priceMax ? v <= (this as any).priceMax : v >= 0;
    },
  },
},
updatedAt: { type: Date },
updatedBy: { type: String },
```

I, sort of, understand what the functions are doing, but the types here confuse me.

How could I get rid of `this as any`? Why not just use `FeePricing` for the type - eg `(this as FeePricing)`? `FeePricing` appears that to be is just another type from my app [, which has `priceMin` and `priceMax`] combined with a `Document` interface. How does the `Document` from ReactJS help here? Why is it needed? Is `this` in `validate` the above-defined type `FeePricing & Document`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the context of your validation configuration. Because TypeScript cannot infer its type (due to the fact that it can be changed to anything), I would recommend creating your own custom type, like `FeePricing`. I am not too sure what properties your current `FeePricing` contains as it was not included in the example, but I would have it as follows:

```
interface FeePricing {
  priceMin?: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number | null,
  priceMax?: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number | null,
  feeType?: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number | null,
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
(this as FeePricing).priceMax
```

The reason why the properties are optional and also `null` is because I can see that some of your logic checks whether they are `undefined` or `null`, hence these types will reflect that they may not exist in runtime and help you validate correctly. Additionally if `FeePricing` type is used for something else you can ofcourse change this type name to something else.

To answer your question about ReactJs `Document`, it does not add any help to infer the mongoose configuration type and can really be removed.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand in Mongoose the schema is used to define the document that is stored in MongoDB. If i am correct you can just create a model/interface of the Feepricing and use that as the type.

```
export interface FeePricing {
  priceMax: number;
  priceMin: number;
}
```

`this` is the FreePricing object.

Hope this helps